# Why is the double colon operator needed in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, callback, method-reference

I'm coming from a JavaScript background and I'm seeing the `::` operator for the first time. I understand what it does, but I'm wondering why it's necessary. In JavaScript, something like this is perfectly valid:

```js
[1, 2, 3].forEach(console.log);
```

There's no need for a new operator - I'm just not calling the `log` function directly/explicitly. So my question is, why doesn't that work in Java? What is there in Java that makes the `Class.method` unusable (masks it?!)?

Comment: `Class.method` could be referring to a field. Perhaps the designers wanted to avoid that ambiguity...

Comment: Because in Java, `console.log` refers to a variable (field).

Comment: In JavaScript functions are first-class objects, so you can simply pass them to a function as arguments. Java doesn't have such a thing, so it needs method references to emulate that.

Comment: there are disadvantages in using that *notation*: reading that code I would need to search what `log` is... a method, a field, ... (at least for unknown objects/methods)

Comment: No you don't, if you know that forEach takes a function as an argument

Comment: True. The trouble with weakly typed languages. That's why TypeScript is popular. No issues there

Answer (score 0):

Because variables and methods do not share the same namespace in Java, so you can have variables and methods with the same name.

This is valid in Java:

```
class Test {
    private static int c;
    private static int c() { return 0; }
}
```

Now what would `Test.c` refer to here if we didn't have the `::` operator?